# Need help understanding using C++ map as an associative array

Tags: c++, dictionary

I was going through Josuttis's "Using Map's as associative arrays" (from [The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference, 2nd Edition](http://www.cppstdlib.com/)) and came across [Using a std::map as an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540182/using-a-stdmap-as-an-associative-array) on Stack Overflow. Now I have more questions on the constructors that are called when inserting into a map.

Here is my sample program (not using best coding practices; please excuse me for that):

```
class C
{
public:

   string s;

   C() { cout << "default " << endl;}

   C(const string& p) : s(p)
   { cout << "one param" << endl;}

   C(const C& obj)
   {
       if (this != &obj)
       {
         s = obj.s;
       }
       cout << "copy constr" << endl;
   }

   C& operator  = (const C& obj)
   {
       if (this != &obj)
       {
             s = obj.s;
       }
      cout << "copy initializer" << endl;
      return *this;
   }
};

int main()
{
    map<int,C> map1;
    C obj("test");

    cout << "Inserting using index" << endl;
    map1[1] = obj;

    cout << "Inserting using insert / pair" << endl;
    map1.insert(make_pair(2,obj));
}
```

The output for this program is:

```
one param
Inserting using index
default
copy constr
copy constr
copy initializer
Inserting using insert / pair
copy constr
copy constr
copy constr
copy constr
```

I was assuming that initializing the map by index should call the default constructor and followed by the assignment operator.

But executing `map1[1] = obj` creates following output;

```
Inserting using index
default
copy constr
copy constr
copy initializer
```

Can someone help me to understand the initialization better?

Comment: You dont need to test for copy construction to self.

Comment: As a matter of fact, now i understand it is better to have pointers than objects in STL containers.

Comment: @mithuna: Warning: Storing pointers instead of objects brings lifetime management issues, so I'd say that it is better to store objects. *If* this causes performance issues, you should see if the copy can be optimized. Then, *if* it can't, you could consider storing pointers instead of objects. In that case, you may be interested in the Boost.PointerContainer library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). ptr_map (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html), in the present case.

Comment: ... or, if you have access to one, use an implementation that supports C++0x move semantics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the specification for std::map, it says that operator[] is equivalent to (in this case)

```
(*((this->insert(make_pair(1,C()))).first)).second
```

So this explains all the constructor calls you see. First it calls the default constructor C(). Then it calls make_pair, which copies the C object. Then it calls insert, which makes a copy of the pair object you just made, calling the C copy constructor again. Finally it calls the assignment operator to set the inserted object to the one you are assigning it to.

Comment: Same as my answer, only better! +1 and deleted mine.

Comment: Nice response, re-read the spec and it did make lot of sense now.

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that with some -O option we might only get one Copy Construction call ? Note that for better performance you could use `iterator insert(iterator pos, value_type const& x)` where `pos` can be deduced using `iterator lower_bound(key_type const&)` (and taking its predecessor if this is valid). You would thus avoid default construction and assignment while not falling into the double search trap.

Answer (score 2):

Don;t know.
But this is interesting:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C
{
    public:
        string s;
        C()
        {
            cout << "default " << endl;
        }
        C(const string& p)
        : s(p)
        {
            cout << "one param(" << s << ")" << endl;
        }
        C(const C& obj)
            :s(obj.s)
        {
           cout << "copy constr(" << s << ")" <<endl;
        }
        C& operator  = (const C& obj)
        {
            cout << "copy initializer\t" <<;

            C copy(obj);
            std::swap(s,copy.s);

            return *this;
        }
};

int main()
{
    map<int,C> map1;
    cout << "Inserting using index" << endl;
    map1[1] = C("Plop");
}
```

It looks like the default one is created and copied around.
Then the external one is just assinged over it once it has been put in place.

```
Inserting using index
default
copy constr()
copy constr()
one param(Plop)
copy initializer      copy constr(Plop)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you simply execute `map[1];`? This may involve internal copies, depending on the implementation of `map` your standard library uses.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `map1[1] = obj` will create `pair` first