# How to check that Qwidget exist 

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Like in title how to check that child class from QWidget exist?

when i try something like that it break application end throw error

```
void MainWindow::slotAddLoginData() {
    if(!addLoginData) {
        addLoginData = new AddLoginData(this);
        connect(this, SIGNAL(setEnabledALDbtnOK(bool)),
        addLoginData, SLOT(btnOkEnabled(bool)));

    }
    addLoginData->show();
    addLoginData->activateWindow();

}
```

Comment: Where does it break? What error does it throw?

Comment: Unexpected end of program. When i remove "if" statements everything is allright

Comment: Run it with a debugger (e.g. GDB on \*NIX systems) and tell us *where* it breaks.

Comment: Error occure when addLoginData->show(); is called

Comment: Is it a segmentation fault? My guess is that your parent class isn't initialising addLoginData to NULL.

Comment: exactly! setting NULL in the constructor solves the problem, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `addLoginData` is not initialised

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, addLoginData isn't initialized. You can't do this:

`if(!addLoginData) { ... }`

Unless you initialize addLoginData to 0.
So, as Georg said, initialize it, except make that..

`MainWindow::MainWindow() : addLoginData(0)`

(note the "0")

Comment: `addLoginData()` and `addLoginData(0)` do exactly the same thing here - default initialization means zero initialization in case of scalar types... See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936999/what-is-the-default-constructor-for-c-pointer).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be that you have not initialized `addLoginData`. Use something like this in that case:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
  : addLoginData()
  // ...
{
    // ...
}
```