# Behavior of calling operator [] when no mapped value is assigned to the key

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, operators, g++

I have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {

    std::map<int, int*> mapaString;
    int* teste = mapaString[0];
    std::cout << teste << std::endl;
    if(!teste)
        mapaString[0] = new int(0);

    std::cout << mapaString[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << mapaString[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In documentation at [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00592.html#a4a4a9f95131baf0713596d672ec36b5f) and [cpluplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/) it's just said that will be called the default constructor of the element, but when a pointer is declared without initializing it, its value will be undefined.

Is it guaranteed that the value returned will be a NULL pointer when calling subscript operator([]) when there is no mapped value assigned to the key and return type is a pointer?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936999/what-is-the-default-constructor-for-c-pointer

Comment: @TheUndeadFish Yeah, in essence is equal. Thanks, I had only researched for map container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "default constructors" of primitive types (including pointers) produce 0-filled memory, much like global variables.

Here is the relevant standard language (from dcl.init):

> To default-initialize an object of
>   type T means:
>
> --if  T is a non-POD class type
>   (*class*), the default constructor for
>       T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has
>   no acces-
>       sible default constructor);
>
> --if T is an array type, each
>   element is default-initialized;
>
> --otherwise, the storage for the
>   object is zero-initialized.
>
> ...
>
> 7 An  object whose initializer is an
>   empty set of parentheses, i.e., (),
>   shall be default-initialized.

Also, from lib.map.access:

> 23.3.1.2  map element access                          [lib.map.access]
>
> reference operator[](const key_type&
>   x);
>
> Returns:
>       (*((insert(make_pair(x, T()))).first)).second.

Answer (score -1):

Just like any uninitialized variable, you cannot assume this will be initialized properly to value. It will depend on your build, release or debug, your compiler, your platform, etc. I would probably do this:

```
if(mapaString.find(key) == mapaString.end()) { mapaString[0] = 0; }
```

Then you can be sure the pointer for key was initialized to 0 / NULL.

Comment: Actually it will be value-initialized which will initialize basic types to null/0. Also doing the `find` and then `[]` does two searches on the `map` , which can be avoided.

Comment: Ah. I've just been bitten by the uninitialized bug too many times, I thought it pertained to this as well.