# Is the default value of an int* NULL?

Tags: c++, templates

I have written the following source

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class AAA
{
public:
    void f() { cout << T() << " "; }
};

int main ( void )
{
    AAA<int*> a;
    AAA<int> b;

    a.f(); /// in this case, T() == NULL??
    b.f(); 

    return 0;
}
```

and console print is 00000000 0. ( in visual studio 2010 )

if T is int*, T() == NULL? and is it always true?

Comment: Yup. Always. http://stackoverflow.com/a/937257/707111

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default constructor for C++ pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936999/what-is-the-default-constructor-for-c-pointer)

Answer (score 9):

This is called **value-initialization**, you are guaranteed `0`.

Plus, you don't need such a complicated example to demonstrate:

```
typedef int* T;
int main()
{
   T x = T();
   std::cout << x;
}
```

Comment: God, 55k reputation and you still answer those silly question in less than a minute. Why don't you keep your knowledge for more complicated question, giving to newcomers the chance to build some reputation?

Comment: I see. I upvoted your answer, to support reaching your milestone :P

Answer (score 8):

Yes. A value-initialized pointer is always null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is null pointer. And why it is printing:

```
00000000
```

because it is using 4-byte to represent the null-address (in hexadecimal format).

On 64-bit machine, it *may* print this instead (hexadecimal format):

```
0000000000000000
```