# How to find acess a class-method of objects stored in c++ vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, object, stl

I am C++ noob, forgive me if this a simple question, I have been trying to solve this problem since past couple of days.

There exists a  class called student which stores names, age and marks of a student. Each student's profile (age, name and marks is stored in a class). There are `n` students in a class hence , a `vector<student*>` is created, which stores the pointers to all the students profile in a class.

I want to print the values stored in the `vector I would really appreciate any hints!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class student{
private:
    string name;
    float marks;
    int age;
public:
    student(): name("Null"), marks(0),age(0){}
    student(string n, float m,int a): name(n), marks(m),age(a){}
    void set_name();
    void set_marks();
    void set_age();
    void get_name();
    void get_marks();
    void get_age();
};
void student::set_name(){
cout<<"Enter the name: ";
cin >> name;
}
void student::set_age(){
cout << "Enter the age: ";
cin >> age;
}
void student::set_marks(){
cout<<"Enter the marks ";
cin>> marks;
}
void student::get_name(){
    cout<<"Name: "<< name<<endl;
}
void student::get_age(){
    cout<<"Age: "<< age<<endl;
}

void student::get_marks(){
    cout<<"Marks: "<< marks<<endl;
}


int main() {
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> n;
    vector <student*> library_stnd(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        student* temp = new student;
        temp->set_name();
        temp->set_age();
        temp->set_marks();
        library_stnd.push_back(temp);

    }


    for (auto ep: library_stnd){
         ep->get_age();
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: 1) Did you try consulting your [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)? 2) What is your specific question? SO is not a tutorial service, and, currently, your "question" is too broad.

Comment: _"I haven't even been able to ..."_ - well, what happened? Did it compile? What was the compile error? Did it crash? What was shown, and what have you tried to debug it? Or was the output not what you expected?

Comment: @Useless It compiles takes all the input  but does not give any output

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius My question is how do use class methods for  the values of classes stored in the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector <student*> library_stnd(n)` create a vector of size `n`. Then in the first for loop `library_stnd.push_back(temp)` push `temp` to the end of library_stnd and does not change first `n` items.

The problem is the first `n` items in `library_stnd` is zero initialized[1] and dereferencing it in the second for loop is an undefined behavior.[2]

My suggestions is using either one of the following:

1. `vector <student*> library_stnd` and `library_stnd.push_back(temp)`
2. `vector <student*> library_stnd(n)` and `library_stnd[i] = temp`

Another suggestion

1. `vector<student>` instead of `vector<*student>`, then `for (auto& ep: library_stnd)`
2. `'\n'` instead of `endl` [3]
3. `double` instead of `float` [4]

[1] - [What is the default constructor for C++ pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936999/what-is-the-default-constructor-for-c-pointer)

[2] - [C++ standard: dereferencing NULL pointer to get a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727834/c-standard-dereferencing-null-pointer-to-get-a-reference)

[3] - [C++: "std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

[4] - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188721/when-do-you-use-float-and-when-do-you-use-double